How to use DiscriminatorColumn with Generic Entities
Given the following entity classes...
Product
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class Basket<T> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Type type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "???", referencedColumnName = "id")
    // how do I set name to vehicle_id or publication_id depending on T?
    private T product;
}

Vehicle
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("VEHICLE")
public class Vehicle extends Product<Car> {}

Publication
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("PUBLICATION")
public class Publication extends Product<Book> {}

How do I provide a different column name in @JoinColumn for the different types (i.e. Vehicle and Publication)?
